# how to setup Qt5 static in window 10 using command line

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5

i am compile dynamic Qt5 and getting binaries successfully. but when i move my binaries to other compile i am getting QT5gui.dll missing Error . so now i want to setup Qt5 statically . and also want to know how to set environment variables please help me .

Comment: take a look here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html , this could help you too: https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows

Answer (score 0):

a good guide for this (static deployment) can be found here:
https://boffinblogger.blogspot.com/2018/12/static-compile-of-qt-5120-using-visual.html

It  will take quite some time to run the nmake/jom step if you have a computer with a lower number of cores. Definitely use Jom instead of nmake if you can.

Also, if your only problem is that when you move the dynamic binaries you get the dll errors, you need to run windeployqt.exe in the location of your exe (example path: C:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin\windeployqt.exe).
open cmd, cd to the location of your new program and paste the path of the windeployqt.exe for the qt version that you used.

Comment: i am using mingw for Qt and i am trying to compile the altcoin on window using QT 5.10.1 and i already tried the windeployqt.exe its is creating file but still i am getting error _ZdaPvj could not be located in the dynamic link library \c:\myproject\relase\QT5Core.dll

Comment: https://ibb.co/m0393Sn check the Error what i am getting for i tried the windeployqt.exe ...

Comment: when i give then PATH from the variable environment then my binary is working fine but when remove its not working giving error like (_ZdaPvj could not be located in the dynamic link library \c:\myproject\relase\QT5Core.dll ) after using the windeployqt.exe

Comment: @Awaissakhi that error means that the deployed dlls are not compatible with your program, my guess is that the dlls are for msvc not mingw which you use

Comment: thanks bro i resolved this .. i just copy and past all dll file in my binary file directory so its start working .. your information is very helpful